# MySQL - Bin folder

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to learn all the binary files inside the mysql bin folder,but unfortunately I couldn't able to find the detailed explanation of these.So please tell me the procedure to have good knowledge about the files.

Comment: I think you need to focus on the OS here. The normal thing to do with Unix is type the command and put "--help" at the end of the line and then hit return. This should explain what the command does and then list the options and what they do. Not that sure under windows ("-help"?) or run the command with no arguments from the DOS prompt.

Comment: It is a good question, I am sorry for the downvotes.

Comment: yeah mate,I tried that, unfortunately i just gives all the possible parameters instead giving why I used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need to do is ***read is the MySQL Documentation***

## CLASSES OF EXECUTABLES

- [Client Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/programs-client.html) : These programs require you to login to to MySQL to perform SQL commands, dump, imports, consistency checks, and other database/table operations.
- [Utilities](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/programs-admin-utils.html) : These programs check for statistics on tables, perform table repairs, do table compression, analyze logs,  and things like these. Some of these program require logging in. Other programs require reading and updating table characteristics without allowing shared usage of the table by client programs or the table being manipulated may become corrupt.
- [Installation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/programs-installation.html) : Some programs perform installation and post-installation aspects of MySQL
- [Server Startup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/programs-server.html) : These programs execute the startup of MySQL, the monitoring of a MySQL termination, and the configuration of multiple MySQL instances.

## SUMMARY

After reading these, you should develop a healthy respect for the binary executables and a responsible attitude towards running them.

Comment: @RonaldoMySQLDBA thanks.I helped a bit :)